# SD Card disappear from Windows on Macbook Pro after waking up

Tags: windows-7, mac, sleep, macbook-pro, sd-card

I have the SD Card for my Macbook Pro running Windows. Every time the laptop goes to sleep and wake up, the SD Card disappear. It only comes back if you restart - I tried install new BootCamp driver, reinstall the USB hub, reset SMC but none help so far.

[image]

I have been searching for solution and the only related topic I saw is [SD Card Slot Disappears After Sleep (Gone Until Reboot)](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5408471?start=30&tstart=0)
 on Apple forum. Look like lots of people having my problem too.

Anyone got a permanent working solution or less annoying than reset the computer ?

Comment: Same symptom observed on Ubuntu (14.04)

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple partitions on SD card, try **repartitioning it to a single partition**

Windows don't support multiple partitions in a removable disk. I got the problem while trying to DIY fusion drive using an SD card, and solved it by removing a fusion drive.

You can repartition the disk using MiniTools Partition Wizard. (Free for Home) My current settings is like this: Most of the SSD part is dedicated to macOS.

[image]